# Is there any reliable way to identify a device from a web app?

Tags: html, security

I'm working on an Html 5 application which works offline using local storage and application cache.

One of the requirements is to restrict the user to a single device (to prevent data ending up in local storage on a public machine for example). It should also be possible to identify a particular device when connecting and trigger a remote wipe.

I'm currently storing a token in local storage that is matched against the user's record on the server each time they reconnect. But a savvy user could of course simply copy this across to another browser /device.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Note: I cannot use native code / deploy inside a native app, so javascript only. I think this means I will struggle to get any unique device id.

Comment: Browsers cannot do what you want. You need a native app.

Comment: JS can only access what the browser it's running in provides. If it was possible to get (say) the IMEI via javascript, you'd think every single mobile ad company on the planet would be exploiting that hole to hell and back.